# how to apply a style to all child elements of a particular type in scss?

Tags: css, sass

How can I apply a style to all child elements of a particular type in scss? For example, let's say I want to be able to apply a class named 'radioCircles' to a div which will apply border-radius:10px to all radio buttons within that div.  The div may have other types of elements as well but I only want the style to be applied to radio buttons.

Comment: So… `.radioCircles input[type=radio]`?

Comment: using normal css you would use `.radioCircles input[type="radio"] { border-radius: 10px; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SCSS you would define:

```
.radioCircles {
  /* put any styling for the class here */
  input[type="radio"] {
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
```